# Onenote shortcut to change mouse cursor from pen mode to text mode

Tags: shortcuts, microsoft-onenote, graphics-tablet, windows-tabletpc

I am using Wacom tablet with Onenote. When I move my pen inside the page, it defaults to pen mode. If I want to change to text mode I have to click the toolbar.

What is the shortcut for changing from pen mode to text mode?

It is so annoying, since whenever I am pasting something, it goes back to pen mode and I have to move my pen again to click into the text mode.

Comment: Welcome to this site! Which version of OneNote are you using?

Comment: I am using onenote 2007. Thanks
I found this thread that might help others
http://www.technologyquestions.com/technology/microsoft-onenote/351649-keyboard-shortcut-switch-between-pen-tool-keyboard-typing.html

Comment: URL link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

In OneNote 2013, alt-d then p the ENTER gives you the pen. Alt-d then t gives you text mode. Using AutoHotkey you can bind these sequences of keys to any hotkey you like. Works for any other thing accessible via the menu as well.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on GuoLiang's answer.
There is an option to switch to the text cursor under the Menu `Draw`. Depending on your language settings in OneNote, the shortcuts might differ, but you can view them by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and later (as a character sequence) the corresponding characters that are displayed under the menu.

Thus, in german layout, the following *sequence* works

> <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

to switch to the text cursor in OneNote 2016.

According to GuoLiang, the english version should be

> <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

If this shortcut is too long for your taste, I recommend a tool like AutoHotkey to map your own combination to this sequence of keystrokes.